# problem with alarm manager delay in alarm ringing

Tags: android, android-layout, timepicker, android-timepicker

I have encountered a problem where when I set a time, there is a delay for the alarm to ring. Sometimes the alarm goes off early too. I am not sure where I did wrong. Hope someone can help me with this problem.

```
public void showHourPicker(View view) {


    currentHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {

            if (hourOfDay >= 12) {
                amPm = "PM";
            } else {
                amPm = "AM";
            }
            txtTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d ", hourOfDay, minutes) + amPm);

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minutes);
        }

    }, currentHour, currentMinute, false);

    timePickerDialog.setTitle(" Your Expected Time : " + exp.getText());
    timePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    timePickerDialog.show();

    startAlarm(calendar);

}

public void startAlarm(Calendar calendar) {

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intended behavior as described in [`AlarmManager.setRepeating`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> As of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above.

Comment: so i should use alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);

Like this ?

Comment: Yes - and You can schedule next exact alarm in your broadcast receiver if You need exact repetition.

Comment: when I try it does not ring

Answer (score 0):

`setRepeating` is equal to `setInexactRepeating` above API 19. If you want to repeat it exactly after a fixed interval then use `handler.postDelayed` in your Broadcast Receiver. I have attached one of my Broadcast Receiver code with the same implementation

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private MediaPlayer alarmRinger;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent alarmIntent) {
   alarmRinger = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alarmringer);
   runnable.run();
   }
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        alarmRinger.start();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3600000);//Change the timing accordingly in MS 
    }
};
```

}

Here my `AlarmManager` triggers the Broadcast Receiver and the Broadcast receiver then triggers `MediaPlayer` to create a mediaPlayer for playing the sound and also triggers `runnable.run()` which causes `Runnable` to run. When the runnable is triggered, the mediaPlayer runs and plays the sound and then the `handler.postDelayed` is set to repeat the task of Runnable again in 1 hour (3600000 ms), this is repeated infinitely or till you kill the runnable.